# Issue with mysql_real_escape_string() syntax

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I've been doing some research on  mysqli_real_escape_string() but I'm not really understanding how to properly use it in my case to help protect against SQLInjection, Using my code below, can someone help me correct this? I appreciate all the help. The other questions on here reguarding sql injection and php did not really answer my question reguarding the proper syntax usage in my format, When I used this:

```
"$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['City']);
```

I got just my generic search no matter what the input of '%$city%' or '%$business%'

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect(........);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
       echo "<option>Failed to connect to the Database</option>" ;
       }


     $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['City']);
     $business = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Business']);

     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Business WHERE City LIKE '%$city%' AND BName LIKE '%$business%' ORDER BY City, BName ASC");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
     {
     // do stuff here
     }

     // No other results
     echo "<center>No other listings like $city or $business</center>";

     // Free result set
     mysqli_free_result($result);
     mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Forget about `mysql_real_escape_string()` and the legacy mysql extension—it's abandoned and insecure. If you are using the new mysqli extension, use it all the time (among other reasons, because you can't mix two different database extensions). Prepared statements are the way to go; period.

Comment: I apologize that was a mistype on my part, I am using mysqli its just sanitizing ALL input, so my search keeps ending up being '%%' instead of '% USERS INPUTS IN VARIABLE FORM %'

Comment: If you have problems with your code, please post the real code. If want to prevent SQL Injection, please use prepared statements rather than escape functions.

Comment: Ok, I will look into prepared statements, Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of  `mysql_real_escape_string` because you are using `mysqli_*` functions.

> string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

You have to rewrite your escape sequences to

```
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['City']);
$business = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $_POST['Business']);
```

And for preventing `sql injection` use `prepaid statements` instead.

Comment: I apologize that was a mistype on my part, I am using mysqli its just sanitizing ALL input, so my search keeps ending up being '%%' instead of '% USERS INPUTS IN VARIABLE FORM %' The search works perfectly when I'm not using mysqli_real_escape_string()